This page isn't available in Salesforce Lightning Experience or mobile app - LWC
I am not able to navigate from one component to another. Please suggest. I am using standard_component and componentName: c__Payment_Details to navigate the Payment_Details Lightning App page after clicking on select button. Is there any changes needs to be done in componentName. Is there any other code should I share with this select code?
hotelSearch.js:
import { LightningElement, track } from 'lwc';
import { NavigationMixin } from 'lightning/navigation';
import getHotels from '@salesforce/apex/HotelController.getHotels';

// Define columns for lightning-datatable
const columns = [
    { label: 'City', fieldName: 'Hotel_City__c' },
    { label: 'Hotel Type', fieldName: 'Hotel_Type__c' },
    { label: 'WiFi Availability', fieldName: 'WiFi_Availability__c', type: 'boolean' },
    { label: 'Cancellation Availability', fieldName: 'Cancellation_Availability__c', type: 'boolean' },
    { label: 'Cash Pay Availability', fieldName: 'Cash_Pay_Availability__c', type: 'boolean' }
];

export default class HotelSearch extends NavigationMixin(LightningElement) {
    @track hotels = [];
    @track selectedRows = [];
    hotelCity = '';
    selectedHotelType = '';
    hotelTypes = [
        { label: '3 Star', value: '3 Star' },
        { label: '4 Star', value: '4 Star' },
        { label: '5 Star', value: '5 Star' }
    ];

    // Handle changes in the hotel city input
    handleHotelCityChange(event) {
        this.hotelCity = event.target.value;
    }

    // Handle changes in the hotel type combobox
    handleHotelTypeChange(event) {
        this.selectedHotelType = event.detail.value;
    }

    // Perform search action
    handleSearch() {
        getHotels({ hotelCity: this.hotelCity, hotelType: this.selectedHotelType })
            .then(result => {
                this.hotels = result;
            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.error('Error fetching hotels: ' + JSON.stringify(error));
            });
    }

    // Handle row selection in the datatable
    handleRowSelection(event) {
        this.selectedRows = event.detail.selectedRows;
        console.log('Selected Rows:', this.selectedRows);
    }

    // Handle select button action
    handleSelect() {
        if (this.selectedRows.length === 0) {
            alert('Please select a hotel');
            return;
        }

        const selectedHotelId = this.selectedRows[0].Id; // Assuming single selection
        if (!selectedHotelId) {
            console.error('Selected Hotel ID is undefined');
            return;
        }

        console.log('Selected Hotel ID:', selectedHotelId);

        this[NavigationMixin.Navigate]({
            type: 'standard__component',
            attributes: {
                componentName: 'c__Payment_Details' // Ensure correct component name and namespace
            },
            state: {
                c__hotelId: selectedHotelId // Pass any necessary parameters
            }
        }).then(() => {
            console.log('Navigation success');
        }).catch((error) => {
            console.error('Navigation error:', error);
        });
    }

    // Getter for checking if there are search results
    get hasResults() {
        return this.hotels && this.hotels.length > 0;
    }

    // Getter for columns
    get columns() {
        return columns;
    }
}

paymentComponent.js
import { LightningElement, api, wire } from 'lwc';
import { ShowToastEvent } from 'lightning/platformShowToastEvent';
import savePayment from '@salesforce/apex/PaymentController.savePayment';
import { NavigationMixin } from 'lightning/navigation';

export default class PaymentComponent extends NavigationMixin(LightningElement) {
    @api hotelId; // Receive hotelId from URL parameters
    cardNumber = '';
    expiryMonth = '';
    expiryYear = '';
    cvv = '';

    handleInputChange(event) {
        const field = event.target.name;
        if (field === 'cardNumber') {
            this.cardNumber = event.target.value;
        } else if (field === 'expiryMonth') {
            this.expiryMonth = event.target.value;
        } else if (field === 'expiryYear') {
            this.expiryYear = event.target.value;
        } else if (field === 'cvv') {
            this.cvv = event.target.value;
        }
    }

    handleSubmit(event) {
        event.preventDefault(); // Prevent default form submission

        savePayment({
            payerDetailsId: this.hotelId,
            cardNumber: this.cardNumber,
            expiryMonth: this.expiryMonth,
            expiryYear: this.expiryYear,
            cvv: this.cvv
        })
        .then(result => {
            // Handle success response
            this.dispatchEvent(
                new ShowToastEvent({
                    title: 'Success',
                    message: 'Payment saved successfully',
                    variant: 'success',
                }),
            );

            // Redirect to payment detail page
            this[NavigationMixin.Navigate]({
                type: 'standard__recordPage',
                attributes: {
                    recordId: result.Id,
                    objectApiName: 'Payment_Master__c',
                    actionName: 'view'
                }
            });
        })
        .catch(error => {
            // Handle error response
            this.dispatchEvent(
                new ShowToastEvent({
                    title: 'Error saving payment',
                    message: error.body.message,
                    variant: 'error',
                }),
            );
        });
    }
}


Make sure that the target component is configured js-mata.xml file with the lightning__AppPage or lightning__RecordPage target.

In js-meta.xml both lines are included.
